# Xaringan presentation in modules

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

Is it possible to create a presentation based on several .Rmd files? I'm working on one that's becoming too complex and i'd like to break it into separated files for each slide, like chapters works in {bookdown}.

Answer (score 2):

I think as long as you have them formatted for properly work with Xarigan presentation you can do something like this

````
```{r child = 'chapter1.Rmd'}
```

```{r child = 'chapter2.Rmd'}
```
````